# How to setup a rule to redirect to shopping cart?

Tags: 7, commerce, rules

I am trying to create a rule that after a user creates an account they are sent to a Checkout page that will eventually have them pay via PayPal ( I am using the Commerce Module ).

My steps so far have 
1.  Created an event "After saving a new user account"
2.  Leave Condition blank.
3.  Select Action of Complete Checkout For an Order

At step three it asks for a Data Selector: "Select data of the type Commerce Order." and I have no idea where to go from here.

Comment: add a link, menu or button in user profile, at main menu, .... visible when a user loggs in, inside button link href="/cart"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're probably missing a step, if I was integrating this I would create a product called Subscription (or something similar)

Your rule actions should be something like:

1. Add product Subscription to cart
2. Go to checkout

Comment: This is getting there, but really you first need to create the order as a shopping cart for the registered user, then you can add the product to it and redirect the user to checkout/[order-id].

Comment: So this is my current thinking/workflow.  Person visits site and wants to become a member, so they go to user/register, complete that, which redirects  via LoginTobaggan to the profile2 page.  I followed the comment above and created a product called Subscription, and then the two rules, but once a new user is created, it just stays at the Profile2 page.  Is LoginTobaggan the issue or am I not quite getting the Rules written correctly?